# Is Gson TypeAdapter support skip value parsing when it access an invalid field?

Tags: android, gson

## Background

I have a data class:

```
data class Foo(
    @SerializedName("foo")
    val foo: Int = 1000
)
```

I want to use this IntSafeTypeAdapter to deserialize to Foo object. But the json string will return an invalid `foo` unexpectedly. So I custom a Gson TypeAdapter to solve it.

And a Gson TypeAdapter:

```
class IntSafeTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<Int>() {
    override fun write(reader: JsonWriter?, intValue: Int?) {
        reader?.value(intValue ?: return)
    }

    override fun read(reader: JsonReader?): Int {
        val numStr = reader?.nextString()
        if (numStr == null) {
            // 1. How to skip this field and using kotlin data class default value
            // when there is no value of this field?
            return 0
        }
        if (numStr.toLong().toInt() != numStr.toInt()) {
            // 2. How to skip this field and using kotlin data class
            // when there is a long value?
            return numStr.toInt()
        }
        // common condition
        return numStr.toInt()
    }
}
```

## Question

And my question is comment on the code:

1. when gson access a field that its value is null, how to skip this value's parsed and use kotlin data class default value instead?
2. when gson access a field that its value is a long value, which is will occur an overflow exception(NumberFormatException) when parse to Int, how to skip this value's parsed and use kotlin data class default value instead?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I custom an TypeAdapter to do this:

```
class IntSafeTypeAdapter: TypeAdapter<Int?>() {
    override fun write(reader: JsonWriter?, intValue: Int?) {
        reader?.value(intValue ?: return)
    }

    override fun read(reader: JsonReader?): Int? {
        val numberStr = reader?.nextString() ?: return null
        return try {
            numberStr.toInt()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            // if return null, primitive field will not be set value
            null
        }
    }
}
```

And registerTypeAdapter when build Gson instance:

```
val gson by lazy {
    GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Int::class.java, IntSafeTypeAdapter())
        .create()
}
```

How does it work?
We can read Gson source code `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` to find answer:

```
// ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory
public final class ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    ...
    private ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.BoundField createBoundField(...) {
        ...
        return new ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.BoundField(...) {
            ...
            @Override void read(JsonReader reader, Object value) 
                    throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
                Object fieldValue = typeAdapter.read(reader);
                if (fieldValue != null || !isPrimitive) {  // <<<<<< here
                    field.set(value, fieldValue);
                }
            }
            ...
            
        } 
    }
    ...
}
```

When execute `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.BoundField.read`, if value is not null or is not primitive, the value will be set into this field.

But the value is null and it's primitive so that the field will not be set and use default value instead.